# Save configuration through custom options class in asp.net core

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core

I wrote a Configuration provider according to [this (Basic sample of Entity Framework custom provider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#in-memory-provider-and-binding-to-a-poco-class) article.

There I also override the Set method of the [base class](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationProvider.cs) to save the configuration back to the database.

```
public virtual void Set(string key, string value)
{
   // save key / value pair to db.
}
```

This also works fine if I save the configuration like this:

```
IConfiguration configuration = ...
configuration["Key"] = "value";
```

But this does not work if I want to save it through a custom options class:

```
public class MyOptions
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyOptions _options;

    public HomeController(IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _options.Key = "new value"; // <-- not calling the set in my provider
    }
}
```

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

---

**Update**

I know that the configuration framework is not able to track changes I did to `MyOptions` and therefor it cannot update it automagically. But is there an other way to trigger to save the configuration?

Comment: do you mean `_options.Key = "new value"` ?

Comment: @Romain oh, yes. Thanks

Comment: the Set method is probably only called in the deserialisation of the configuration class, i.e. when you set the value in your `MyOptions` instance, it stays there… Why don't you implement you action on the `MyOptions.Key` setter ?

Comment: @Romain thanks for your response. The deserialisation is done in the Load() method. (see https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) I don't want to implement it in the setter as it is a poco and it's not the responsibility of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If your options types are simple (with no nested classes and collections), you can achieve storing changes to IConfigurationProvider after modifying you typed options class by using [MutableOptions NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MutableOptions/) *(I am the author of that package)*:

```
IOptionsMutator<SimpleOptions> optionsMutator;
optionsMutator.Mutate(options => options with { Bar = 42 });
```

Essentially what [IOptionsMutator implementation](https://github.com/dombrovsky/MutableOptions/blob/main/MutableOptions/Internal/OptionsMutator.cs) does is:

1. Gets IOptionMonitor.CurrentValue.
2. Calls your mutator function on it to get modified options instance.
3. Compares which properties have changed using reflection.
4. Writes changed properties values to IConfiguration.